# Take value of all not null textboes on form and put it in array. C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 6 textboxes on form, but when submits, i want to save the values of only non empty textboxes in winforms, How can i acheive this ?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Show your work first. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.text))..Try before you Ask.

Comment: Loop through all controls of the form and find out each control if it is textbox. Check the value if the textbox text is null or empty as said by @restless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a LINQ-Statement like:

```
string[] textBoxValues = (from tb in Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                            where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text)
                            select tb.Text).ToArray();
```

or

```
string[] textBoxValues = Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(tb => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text)).Select(tb => tb.Text).ToArray();
```

or (if you don't like LINQ)

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
foreach(var textBox in Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
  if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))
  {
    list.Add(textBox.Text);
  }
}
string[] textBoxValues = list.ToArray();
```

Comment: Its Not Working for Datarepeater Controls.